# Nodejs async function return

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero
I'm a nodejs newbie the code is base on this repo

```
  q.awaitAll(function (err, buffers) {
    // if(err) return;
    // console.log(buffers);
    [1, 2, 4].forEach(function (pxRatio) {
        var pngPath = destDir + "/sprite@" + pxRatio + ".png";
        var jsonPath = destDir +  "/sprite@" + pxRatio + ".json";

        spritezero.generateLayout(
          { imgs: buffers, pixelRatio: pxRatio, format: true },
          async function(err, dataLayout) {
            if (err) return;
            let result1 = await client.put(
              jsonPath,
              Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(dataLayout, null))
            );
            //console.log(client.signatureUrl(result.name));
          }
        );
        spritezero.generateLayout(
          { imgs: buffers, pixelRatio: pxRatio, format: false },
          function(err, imageLayout) {
            spritezero.generateImage(imageLayout, async function(err, image) {
              if (err) return;
              let result2 = await client.put(pngPath, image);
              //console.log(client.signatureUrl(result.name));
            });
          }
        );
    });


  });
```

i want to this function have a return value like this in above code,
result1 and result2 is from callback in spritezero.generateLayout

return {pxRatio: [result1.name, result2.name}

Comment: Can you please update the code to show what dependencies there are for your code to run properly? Also, what is the current return value that you are seeing?

Comment: let spritezero = require("@mapbox/spritezero");
var queue = require('queue-async');
the code only use this two lib and another s3 client lib

Comment: I'd love to help, but unfortunately `spriteZero` has a dependency that doesn't support windows on anything above node.js 6, `mapnik`.